How to include custom attributes in asciidoc book
I have an asciidoc book that consists of several .adoc files, and I want to use a custom attribute in each file.
I've created .attribute.adoc and included it in each file like this:
include::.attriutes.adoc[]

It works... but at the end of each chapter (one .adoc file is one chapter) asciidoctor renders the "include statement" as-is. Let's assume .attribute.adc contains the following string:
:appname: MyApp

asciidoctor replaces each occurrence of {appname} with MyApp, but also adds the string :appname: MyApp to the end of the chapter. Any idea?

In the end, the only way to make this work correctly, was to pass the custom attribute (appname) to asciidoctor-pdf. Here's a snippet of my Makefile:
$(PDF_FILE): $(ADOC_FILES) | $(PDF_DIR)
    bundle exec asciidoctor-pdf \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -a appname=$(APPNAME) \
        -a imagesdir=$(IMGDIR) \
        -a pdf-themesdir=$(THEMEDIR) \
        -a pdf-fontsdir="$(THEMEDIR);GEM_FONTS_DIR" \
        -a pdf-theme=custom \
        $(SRCDIR)/main.adoc \
        -o $@

Passing appname to asciidoctor-pdf solves my problem... and the resulting PDF no longer contains :appname: MyApp at end of some chapters.

Where you define attributes matters. It is okay to define an attribute at the start of a block, for example:
:myattr: My Value
This is a new paragraph/block.

However, you cannot define an attribute at the end of a block:
This is a paragraph.
:myattr: My value.

Since there is no blank line between the paragraph and the attribute definition, Asciidoctor assumes the attribute definition is paragraph content.
Since you did not include the problematic markup, I'm guessing this is the source of your problem.

.attributes.adoc contains only 2 lines (custom property :appname: MyApp and an empty line), whereas all the other *.adoc files have include::.attributes.adoc[] at the first line, next an empty line, and then the section title as usual. I checked all my files and I never put the include after or within text.

When you include a file, the file content replaces the include macro as if it had been where the macro was all the time. If you have block content and then an include with no blank line to separate them, you can have the same problem.

This was not the case. I just included .attribute.adoc at the beginning of each file followed by a blank line.

Then the issue may be due to your violation of the expected AsciiDoc structure. If your document has a title, it should be on the first line, followed by the optional author line, attribute definitions, and includes that define attributes, then a blank line to switch to the page content proper.
